# SQL server 2008 - Charting problems

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, charts

I'm trying to create a chart from the below table and ideally would like a line chart with weeks across the bottom, one static sales target line ( Average would work ) and then 4 curve lines for the people. Note: The country and year do not need to be displayed.

Easy to do with a pivot chart in excel, but I am really confused on this one and very new to SQL. Any advise/help would be appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjuSt.jpg

Comment: Table messed up. See the link, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

SQL itself cannot make charts, it can only provide data which other tools can use to make charts from. Using Excel is one solution; other depend on what DBMS you are using and what tools you have available. For example, if you are using SQL Server, then SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) makes this easy (once you've set it up).

But with just SQL - no, no charts.

Comment: Well I do have access to a report designer and so far have managed to put together a line chart with what i require, however only by filtering out one name. If I try to select all names I end up with a name and week for every row across the bottom. I'm sure i have to group these somehow but keep on getting errors when I try.

Comment: OK - set up a new question specifying the tool you're using, what you've tried, what happened and what you want to happen. Cheers -